# Error: Package 'Microsoft SQL Management Studio Package' failed to load. In SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql, ssms

I had installed SQL Server 2008 R2, the installation was succesful. But I can't open the Management Studio because this error is shown: Package 'Microsoft SQL Management Studio Package' failed to load. I'm using Windows 7 Professional SP1 32 bits. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried rerunning the installer?

Answer (score 1):

First check your shortcut, make sure it's C:\program files... and not \computername\C$\program...

Second try a reinstall via:
start /wait :\setup.exe /qb REINSTALL=SQL_Tools90 REINSTALLMODE=OMUS

If thats not the issue have you changed any .Net permissions? Have you tried reverting them back?

Answer (score 1):

Just delete (rename) registry key: **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server**

via (http://blog.dotsmart.net/2012/01/04/solution-for-package-microsoft-sql-management-studio-package-failed-to-load)

Comment: Omg... It was 2011 post.
How it apperars 'modified' now and comes to top?